# Difference between waveform and truth table

Tags: digital-logic, waveform, truth-table

Is there a difference between waveform and truth table to represent the values of a circuit?

For example:

[image]

Are there particular cases where one or the other should be used?

Answer (score 1):

Both can convey the same information if you only want to describe the steady state behavior of a [*combinatorial logic* circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic).

Waveform pictures additionally can convey time-dependent behaviors (a.k.a., [*transient behaviors*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/233594/69405)) of circuits, and they often are drawn for that purpose. Also, they could be drawn to describe changing states of simple [*sequential logic* circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_logic).